# About coordinator and datanode in Postgres-XL

Tags: postgresql, postgres-xl

thanks for your help.
I failed to build  a Postgres-XL  cluster. 
My gtm.confg :

```
listen_addresses = '0.0.0.0'
port = 6668
```

at 10.80.19.47.
My gtm_proxy.confg:

```
listen_addresses = '0.0.0.0'
port = 6666
gtm_host = '10.80.19.47'
gtm_port = 6668
```

after start gtm and gtm_proxy ,i show net information use ***lsof -i*** :

```
gtm       11730 postgres    6u  IPv4 355914      0t0  TCP 10.80.19.47:ircu-4->10.80.19.46:44017 (ESTABLISHED
gtm       11730 postgres    7u  IPv4 355915      0t0  TCP 10.80.19.47:ircu-4->10.80.19.46:44018 (ESTABLISHED)
gtm       11730 postgres    8u  IPv4 355916      0t0  TCP 10.80.19.47:ircu-4->10.80.19.46:44019 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Then i configure datanode like:

```
listen_addresses = '0.0.0.0'
port = 5432
pooler_port = 20002
gtm_host = '127.0.0.1'
gtm_port = 6666
```

and coordinator like:

```
listen_addresses = '0.0.0.0'
port = 3456
pooler_port = 20003
gtm_host = '127.0.0.1'
gtm_port = 6666
```

others are default ,then i start datanode with :

```
/usr/postgres-xl-9.2/bin/postgres --datanode -D /data1/pgsql/data &
```

start coordinator with:

```
/usr/postgres-xl-9.2/bin/postgres --coordinator -D /data1/pgsql/coordinator &
```

when i connect to Postgres-XL  use coordinator with :

```
 psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 3456 postgres;
```

when i want to create a database with:

```
 create database test;
```

but failed,it shows :

```
No Datanode defined in cluster
You need to define at least 1 Datanode with CREATE NODE.
```

then i check the cluster with :

```
 psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 3456  postgres  -c "select * from pgxc_node order by 1";
```

it shows just one node like:

```
node_name     | node_type | node_port | node_host | nodeis_primary | nodeis_preferred |  node_id  
-------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+------------------+-----------
coordinator_node2 | C         |      5432 | localhost | f              | f                | 738118815
```

and i connect to ***port 5432*** it shows the similar information like:

```
 node_name  | node_type | node_port | node_host | nodeis_primary | nodeis_preferred |  node_id   
------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+------------------+------------
data_node2 | C         |      5432 | localhost | f              | f                | -923817565
```

what wrong with my Configuration?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define datanode something like this.

```
./psql -c "CREATE NODE datanode1 WITH (TYPE = 'datanode', PORT = 7777)" postgres -p 3456 -h 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this question a year after. However, I'd suggest you to use pgxc_ctl command line tool as suggested by the Postgres XL developers themselves. It will keep you away from the hectic tasks of manually configuring the cluster.

You can refer to the official documentation of Postgres XL for this. After you successfully installed pgxc_ctl command line tool, type in

```
prepare config minimal
```

in order to generate a basic configuration file to configure the cluster. Edit your changes in pgxc_ctl/pgxc_ctl.conf accordingly. Type in `exit` and finally you can initialize all the clusters if your configuration is okay. For this, type in

```
pgxc_ctl init all
```

Comment: did you come accross coordinators/data nodes not binding to IP address specified within listen_addresses in their respective postgresql.conf? Maybe you could help with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620071/bind-postgres-xl-coordinator-to-listen-only-on-speciffic-interface